# How to create web service using dropbox, trello, or other domain

Tags: android, web-services

I am making an android app and need **web services** to make my app global.

**Is there any quick start guide on creating web services** by using any free domains like dropbox, trello, etc, so that I just store data in the cloud and use my app from anywhere?

Preferably, it does not need much server coding in PHP, and the response comes in **JSON** form.

I read this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-service-in-a-matter-of-minutes--net-12917) but this is little bit tricky.

Comment: does it work on trello.com? any sample code that you can share? have you found other solutions?

Comment: I did have similar questions when started coding against web api's a while ago. Just edited the question to make it more concise and specific. Hope that helps make it re-opened.

Comment: please vote re-open this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I did a test project with trello.com. Take a look at the [code of example03](https://github.com/minghuadev/android-appdev/blob/master/devexample03/src/com/example/myfirstprj/DisplayMessageActivity.java), the class Netrq. Basically the steps involved are:

- Create a board then a card on trello.com.
- Get your api key and token from trello.com.
- Find your card link, then use trello api via https to post and get and post data to trello card.
- The field on a card is present in the json response. Use trello card fields as you like.

Though it just uses trello card as a data store, not really an official web-service.

The code to push data to trello is [in lua](https://github.com/minghuadev/lua-docs/blob/master/lua-net/t-lua-put.lua), though the idea should be the same.

Comment: Page not found !! :(

Comment: I created the board and card both on trello.com. Now please tell me how to get api key and token ?

Comment: Actually I don't remember. Googled this link: https://trello.com/c/jObnWvl1/25-generating-your-developer-key

Comment: And this: https://trello.com/c/fD8ErOzA/26-getting-a-user-token-and-oauth-urls